# print two different fields of files using

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a LOG:

```
100.100.100.100 - - [08/Mar/2016:07:53:33 +0100] GET /rbt/Utils.do?receiverID=665135085&action=send_sms&senderID=22077&dtocRequest=n&smsText=Tu+PIN+es+95934&isPostMethod=n&subscriberID=665135085&useSameResForConsent=n&mode=WEB
```

I need to display only two fields. Date and subscriberID field (only digits).

I am trying below commands:

```
cut -d" " -f4,7 input.txt | awk -F"subscriberID=" '{print $2}' input.txt | cut -c0-9
```

My output:

```
665135085
```

Required output:

```
08/Mar/2016:07:53:33 +0100 665135085
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*\[([^]]*)\].*subscriberID=([0-9]*).*/\1 \2/' input.txt
```

If you have a weird `sed` that doesn't support "extended" regular expressions (enabled by the `-E` flag), you have to add a `\` before each opening and closing paren:

```
sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*subscriberID=\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \2/' input.txt
```

Comment: dint work. :(

    [sumit.gupta@abc ~]$ sed -E 's/.*\[([^]]*)\].*subscriberID=([0-9]*).*/\1 \2/' input.txt
sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: Which version of `sed` do you have? All "modern" sed versions shoud have it. Try `man sed` or `which sed`, or tell me which os/distro you are on.

Comment: (But first, just try without `-E`... you never know :-)). `-E` just enables "modern" regular expressions, i.e. around 30 years old...

Comment: I tried slightly modifying your command and worked out. :)

`cut -d" " -f4,7 input.txt | sed -r 's/^\[([0-9]{2}\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) .*subscriberID=([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/g'`

Comment: Huh? Why not just use the second version, without `cut`?

Comment: @Sumit, if my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big checkmark to its left.